# Find first occurence in a list if it contains a substring from another list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, string-matching

I am trying to find the first occurence in a string that match the substring from another list. However, I need the result to return a substring from the list which is separated by a ','.

This is what I have so far.

```py
match_list = ['/AAA 123/' , '/ABC 444/']

text = '/AAA 123/BBB 234/,/CC 345/XXX 999/,/ABC 110/BBD 678/KLM 888/,/AAA 111/ABX 777/ABC 444/'
text_list = text.split(',')

# For loop method
for item_to_match in match_list:
    for line in text_list:
        if item_to_match in line:
            print(line)

# List comprehension            
matched_strings_list = [line for line in text_list for item_to_match in match_list if item_to_match in line]

Current result: '/AAA 111/ABX 777/ABC 444/', '/AAA 123/BBB 234/'
Desired result: '/AAA 123/BBB 234/'
```

Both methods gave me a list which is fine but it doesn't order it and I am unable to get the first occurence according to the list.

Comment: if you want to get first occurrence then writing `break` after `print` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by not ordered? are you looking for `startswith`?

```
[i for i in text.split(',') for j in match_list if i.startswith(j)]
Out[120]: ['/AAA 123/BBB 234/']?
```

or is it?

```
[i for j in match_list for i in text.split(',') if j in i]
Out[125]: ['/AAA 123/BBB 234/', '/AAA 111/ABX 777/ABC 444/']
```

Comment: I am just looking for the first instance but the method i used will find all the instances.